# Foreign key reference to a two-column primary key

Tags: sql, schema, primary-key

I'm building a database that must work on MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite. One of my tables has a two-column primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE tournament (
    state CHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
    year INT NOT NULL,
    etc..., 
    PRIMARY KEY(state, year)
);
```

I want a reference to the `tournament` table from another table, but **I want this reference to be *nullable***. Here's how I might do it, imagining that a winner doesn't necessarily have a tournament:

```
CREATE TABLE winner (
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    state CHAR(2) NULL,
    year INT NULL
);
```

If `state` is null but `year` is not, or vice-versa, the table would be inconsistent. I believe the following `FOREIGN KEY` constraint fixes it:

```
ALTER TABLE winner ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY fk (name, state) REFERENCES tournament (name, state);
```

Is this the proper way of enforcing consistency? Is this schema properly normalized?

Comment: Why do you want state and year to be nullable? What does it mean to have a winner in a non-specified tournament?

Comment: The actual schema is more complex, but it makes sense. It's actually for a word that may or may not be linked to a table of definitions, depending on whether the correct definition is known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Rule #1: ALWAYS SAY THE DATABASE YOU'RE USING

Ok, I'm going to suggest you look at the `ON DELETE` clause, and the `MATCH` clause. Because, Pg is fairly SQL compliant I'll point you to the current docs on [`CREATE TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html).

Excerpt:

> These clauses specify a foreign key
>   constraint, which requires that a
>   group of one or more columns of the
>   new table must only contain values
>   that match values in the referenced
>   column(s) of some row of the
>   referenced table. If refcolumn is
>   omitted, the primary key of the
>   reftable is used. The referenced
>   columns must be the columns of a
>   unique or primary key constraint in
>   the referenced table. Note that
>   foreign key constraints cannot be
>   defined between temporary tables and
>   permanent tables.
>
> A value inserted into the referencing
>   column(s) is matched against the
>   values of the referenced table and
>   referenced columns using the given
>   match type. There are three match
>   types: MATCH FULL, MATCH PARTIAL, and
>   MATCH SIMPLE, which is also the
>   default. MATCH FULL will not allow one
>   column of a multicolumn foreign key to
>   be null unless all foreign key columns
>   are null. MATCH SIMPLE allows some
>   foreign key columns to be null while
>   other parts of the foreign key are not
>   null. MATCH PARTIAL is not yet
>   implemented.
>
> In addition, when the data in the
>   referenced columns is changed, certain
>   actions are performed on the data in
>   this table's columns. The ON DELETE
>   clause specifies the action to perform
>   when a referenced row in the
>   referenced table is being deleted.
>   Likewise, the ON UPDATE clause
>   specifies the action to perform when a
>   referenced column in the referenced
>   table is being updated to a new value.
>   If the row is updated, but the
>   referenced column is not actually
>   changed, no action is done.
>   Referential actions other than the NO
>   ACTION check cannot be deferred, even
>   if the constraint is declared
>   deferrable. There are the following
>   possible actions for each clause:

Also, there is a major exception here with MS SQL -- which doesn't permit partial matches (MATCH SIMPLE and MATCH PARTIAL) behaviors in foreign keys (defaults and enforces MATCH FULL). There are workarounds where you create a MATCH FULL index on the part of the table that IS NOT NULL for any of the composite key's constituents.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I edited to specify the DBs I'm using.

Comment: MySQL impliments `MATCH SIMPLE` but does not support having NULL in the candidate keys (referenced), see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html for more info. I'm not sure about sqlite as I *rarely* ever use it.